# Proving $T$ is a linear transformation where $T:\mathcal{P_2}\rightarrow {M_{2,3}}$ is defined by $T(ax^2+bx+c)= \{\{0, a, b\}, \{a + b, c, b\}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I would appreciate if someone would check me to make sure I have done this proof right, and offer advice on if it is possible to simplify the steps.

As far as I am aware to prove $T$ is a linear transformation where $T:\mathcal{P_2}\rightarrow {M_{2,3}}$, defined by $T(ax^2+bx+c)=\left(\begin{matrix}
    0 & a & b \\
    a+b & c & b \\
    \end{matrix}\right)$, is to show  $T$ satisfies $T(\vec u+\vec w)=T(\vec u) + T(\vec w)$ and $T(a\vec u) = aT(\vec u)$.

One way to do this I imagine is to let
$a,c_i, d_i\in \mathbb{R}$ (where $i$ in $c_i, d_i$ represents an index into a list of $\mathbb{R}$ values starting at 1) and $\vec u, \vec w \in \mathcal{P_2}$ where $\vec u = c_1x^2 + c_2x + c_3$ and $\vec w = d_1x^2 + d_2x + d_3$. Then to show  $T(\vec u+\vec w)=T(\vec u) + T(\vec w)$:

\begin{array}{l c l l}
(1)& T(\vec u+\vec w) & = T((c_1x^2 + d_1x^2) + (c_2x + d_2x) + (c_3+d_3)) & \text{... change in notation} \\ 
(2)& & = T((c_1+d_1)x^2 + (c_2+d_2)x + (c_3+d_3))  & \text{... } (\mathbb{R},*) \text{ distributes over } (\mathbb{R},+)\\
(3)&  &=\left(\begin{matrix}
    0 & (c_1+d_1) & (c_2+d_2) \\
    (c_1+c_2)+(d_1+d_2) & (c_3+d_3) & (c_2+d_2) \\
    \end{matrix}\right)   & \text{... def. of } T:P_2\rightarrow M_{2,3} \text{ & } (\mathbb{R},+) \text{ commutative & assoc.} \\
(4)&  &=\left(\begin{matrix}
    0 & c_1 & c_2 \\
    c_1+c_2 & c_3 & c_2 \\
    \end{matrix}\right) + \left(\begin{matrix}
    0 & d_1 & d_2 \\
    d_1+d_2 & d_3 & d_2) \\
    \end{matrix}\right)   & \text {... def. matrix addition} \\
(5)&  &= T(\vec u) + T(\vec w)  & \text{... } T \text{ preserves addition}\\ 
\end{array}

Next to show that $T(a\vec u) = aT(\vec u)$.

\begin{array}{l c l l}
(1)& T(a\vec u) & = T(a(c_1x^2 + c_2x + c_3)) & \text{... change in notation} \\ 
(2)& & =T\left(ac_1x^2+ac_2x+ac_3\right) & \text{... } (\mathbb{R},*) \text{ distributes over } (\mathbb{R},+)\\
(3)&  &=\left(\begin{matrix}
 0 & ac_1 & ac_2 \\
 ac_1+ac_2 & ac_3 & ac_2 \\
\end{matrix}\right)   & \text{... def. of } T:\mathcal{P_2}\rightarrow M_{2,3} \\
(4)&  &=a\left(\begin{matrix}
 0 & c_1 & c_2 \\
 c_1+c_2 & c_3 & c_2 \\
\end{matrix}\right)  & \text {... def. scalar matrix mult.} \\
(5)&  &= aT(\vec u)  & \text{... } T \text{ preserves scalar multiplication}\\ 
\end{array}

Since $T$ preserves addition and scalar multiplication, $T$ satisfies the definition of being a linear transformation.  $\blacksquare$

Are there any errors here or can this be improved? Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for checking me. Any tips to cut down on steps? Or reduce the verbiage? I'm trying to learn how to be as concise as possible with these sorts of things. Thanks again!

Comment: The proof looks fine. The steps are short and simple enough. The one shorter way I can think of is to make use of the equivalent definition of a linear transformation, that $T(a\vec{u} + b\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{u}) + bT(\vec{w})$.